# Redirect rule to remove query string from url using RedirectMatch

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am looking to redirect all pages on a website by removing any that contain ?cont= within the URL using `RedirectMatch 301`.

For example;
`/my-page.html?cont=uk` would 301 redirect to `/my-page.html`

however this needs to also work for URL's with multiple query strings in;
`/my-page.html?cont=uk&size=100` would 301 redirect to `/my-page.html?size=100`

If needed I can supply all of the variations of what cont= can be, there are around 25. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in site root .htaccess to remove `cont=` parameter from any position:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?cont=[^&]*&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,NE,L]

# rest of your rules go here
```